# PyCharm not connecting to Python 3 console

Tags: pycharm

When I code in PyCharm and press **Run**, no window opens to run the program.  Nothing really happens. Do I have to input the coding language when setting up the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create/define a project interpreter first:

```
Go to File -> Settings -> Project: YourProject -> Project Interpreter
```

Choose / create your environment and hit OK. PyCharm can use already exisitng environments or you can create a new one (using pip or anaconda).

Afterwards you also can edit the `Run/Debug configuration` (you can find it in the standard menu bar next to the Run button). Here you have to choose the script that you want to run with your new environment: `Configurations Tab -> Script Path`. But just simply hit run should already invoke the Project Interpreter for your script.

Comment: Thank you for your help!